# Database cleaner wipes out all tables even when using :except option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I'm having an issue with database cleaner on a rails project. I use a sqlite3 database in my test environment, and it has a number of tables containing reference data, populated by the db:test:prepare task, that does not need to be wiped between tests.

I have a number of cucumber scenarios tagged with @javascript using the webdriver driver, and some without that tag.

In my env.rb file, I have configured database cleaner to use the truncation strategy, with the except option:

```
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation, {:except => %w[ignore me]}
```

`DatabaseCleaner.clean` is called after each scenario, and works as expected on the javascript-tagged scenarios.

However, for the non javascript scenarios it is truncating the entire database, including the tables listed in the :except array. I've also tried calling `DatabaseCleaner.clean_with`, which didn't work either.

Comment: Are you using transactional fixtures?

Comment: Tried setting true and false, same issue either way. This definitely seems to be database cleaner related; I put debug statements either side of the call to DatabaseCleaner.clean to confirm the fixture data is getting wiped at exactly that point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was running into a similar error, except I was seeing the problem when running my @javascript scenarios.

After much googling, reading and hair-pulling I came across [**this post**](http://groups.google.com/group/cukes/browse_thread/thread/78922722027f5630)

I looked in the database_cleaner hook file mentioned there (**cucumber-rails-0.4.0/lib/cucumber/rails/hooks/database_cleaner.rb**) and lo-and-behold it sets the database_cleaner strategy to :truncation without exceptions before each scenario with the following tags: @no-txn,@selenium,@culerity,@celerity,@javascript.

```
Before('@no-txn,@selenium,@culerity,@celerity,@javascript') do
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
end
```

I copied and pasted the before statement into my cucumber env.rb file and added my :except statement to it. That seems to have fixed the issue.

Are you certain it's not your @javascript scenarios that are causing the problem?

Comment: Definitely not the javascript scenarios that are the problem. However, I suspect you are right in so far as something must be overriding my database cleaner strategy. I think I'll try explicitly setting it in the before block before each scenario.

Comment: I've done some further investigation. I actually run my javascript-tagged scenarios under another environment, which explains why I wasn't seeing the scenario with those. This issue still exists under 0.4.1 as well, however I've pretty much done what you've said and set the strategy in the before block. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I've had similar problem with **PostgreSQL** and *database_cleaner (1.4.0)*. 
This code wasn't working and truncated all despite the *:except* option:

```
DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation, :except => %w[countries] )
```

I found out you have to provide *full table name to make it work* with PostgreSQL. Following code worked as expected:

```
DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation, :except => %w[public.countries] )
```

**UPDATE:** it seems like this is fixed in *database_cleaner* version 1.4.1 and it works there as expected

Comment: works the other way around aswell `DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation, :only => %w[countries] )` probably obvious but worth mentioning

Comment: is the table name from the schema?

Answer (score 1):

For latest rails version >=6 and database_cleaner (v1.8.5),we do not need to use public prefix for tables. You can add the following in your rails_helper.rb:

```
  tables_to_be_excluded = %w[user_types]
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation, {except: tables_to_be_excluded})
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
```